# jss create is not supported from JSS CLI version 20.0.0

Tags: jss, sitecore-cli

I am trying to create an application for `sitecore 10 JSS` with react. But I am getting the error

```
jss create is not supported from JSS CLI version 20.0.0
```

can you please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

I think with the latest version of `JSS`, you need to use this command.

```
npx create-sitecore-jss
```

This command scaffolds a `JSS` application based on the latest version of `JSS templates`

Follow this article for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-jss-project-for-the-latest-versions-of-jss-and-sitecore.html

To create an application based on an `older version` of `JSS` and `Sitecore`, you need to use this.

```
jss create my-jss-app react --branch release/<version>
```

Follow this article for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/create-a-jss-app-for-an-older-version-of-sitecore.html

Comment: Did it solve your issue?